# How to make the cursor go to the beginning of the line by default when I hit return?

Tags: indentation

When I hit `Enter`/`Return` on my keyboard, the cursor goes to position of character 82 instead of the beginning of the line. This behavior is very confusing to me. Do I need to add something to the configuration file to make sure that the cursor goes to the beginning of the line?

Comment: what kind of file are you editing when thus happens? This behaviour will be determined by the major mode you are in, and the major mode is set by the file type (eg, plain text, C code, JavaScript, orgmode etc)

Comment: I am in Taureg Merlin mode

Comment: If you switch off `electric-indent-local-mode` in the buffer, does the problem persist?

Comment: Looks like automatic indentation. This could be because of a syntax error in the preceding lines.

Comment: @phils Thanks! It was because of `electric-indent-local-mode`